# Sorting by different types using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a `div` like this,
and in `orderBy` I want to write a function 
`<div ng-repeat="item in IdeaList | orderBy: anyFunction()"`

I have html `select box` with four `options` like

- date
- date-reverse
- id
- name

using that `anyFunction()` I want to sort the `div` accordingly.

Json file is:

```
var IdeaList = [{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Dallas",
    "createdOn": "2015-08-31 00:35:14"
}, {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Bevery Hills",
    "createdOn": "2015-08-31 14:35:14"
}, {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "New York",
    "createdOn": "2015-08-31 13:35:14"
}];
```

Give me some knowledge on how to write that function, or any other way to do this type of sorting.

Comment: Read about angular filters and you should be good to go?

Comment: To sort by what field?

Comment: sort by all fields,  id,name,date(ascending and descending) orders

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look at AngulaJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy).

```
ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:predicate:reverse"
```

You can just set for example:

```
$scope.predicate='name';
$scope.reverse=true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$scope.ideaListById = $filter('orderBy')(IdeaList, function(idea) {
    return idea.id;
});
```

Then on the html:

```
<li ng-repeat="idea in ideaListById">{{idea}}</li>
```

And you can sort by different parameters based on the same logic.